# Application send data to web page

Tags: c#, .net

1. I have a web page for data processing. Web page waits for data to process.
2. And I have a C# application for data. I want to send data to open web page. But I don't want to use socket, Post/Get methods or any web request.

Web page and C# application are client side. They run in same Windows at the same time.

I want to send data to web page from C# app. This operation need to be done with Windows OS or some command line based trigger mechanism.

Web page (Chrome tab or Firefox tab; it doesn't matter) should have tab id the work on. With using this id I may be able to send data to web page from C# app.

But I couldn't really find anything useful.

Is there any way to do this? Is it even possible?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand completely but If I don't get you wrong, you can merge two application into one application. Thus you will have a lot of choice like a background services or asynchronous operations etc.

Comment: The problem is i cant merge them becuse i am only responsible for c# application side. İ can only control c# app. So i need a way to send the data to web page without webrequest or socket.
But thanks anyways

Comment: well, the other project that is not c#, where does it put processed data after processing. If you reach easily the source you can do something. I have no other idea than that. Good luck!

Comment: First app have the data. It should be send to web page for processing. After sending the data to web page my job is done. I dont know what happens to data after that. Thanks

Comment: You could write a browser extension to do it

Answer (score 1):

The way I would approach this is this, assuming you are using either WinForms or WPF:

In your application, embed a web browser:

- WPF: https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-webbrowser-control/
- WinForms: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8
- Load the web page in that browser

Establish a two-way communication between your client application and the web page:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/implement-two-way-com-between-dhtml-and-client?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

If using other technologies let me know and I'll update answer.

Comment: Yes, i am using WPF. Witouth embed a web broser in application, can i still establish a two-way or one-way communication between app and web page.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is `Raw TCP/IP connection on browser` but it's not yet fully supported and implemented. If by `Web requests` you mean online requests then what @DevRacker said is the best I know, too.

However consider `TCP/IP`, `Web sockets` and even `REST-APIs` are frequently used for `Inter-Process Communication (IPC)` too, when there is no online transmission of data and the data/command is only transmitted over a local machine.

If I were you, I would use `Web sockets` or maybe a simpler solution such as `Socket-IO`.